# remove SID from URL and redirect 301 with .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite, magento, seo

we have some URLs with SIDs in googles search results we would like to 301 redirect to the pages without the SIDs. so we need an URL rewrite to change this URL

```
http://www.in-due.de/hochzeitsshop/catalogsearch/result/index/?SID=8df077eea401bda0da7e9a980efe20cf&cat=148&dir=asc&limit=9&order=relevance&p=8&q=gold
```

into this url:

```
http://www.in-due.de/hochzeitsshop/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=148&dir=asc&limit=9&order=relevance&p=8&q=gold
```

essentially removing this part:

```
SID=8df077eea401bda0da7e9a980efe20cf&
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login to Google's webmaster tools and under site configuration, parameter handling you'll want to add SID to the list, and you can remove the URLs manually but I would simply use this robots.txt file and let the bots pickup to remove those URLs with the session ID.

Here is the robot.txt file I have been using for Magento sites.  Obviously you may want to tweak as necessary:

```
# $Id: robots.txt,v magento-specific 2010/28/01 18:24:19 goba Exp $
#
# robots.txt
#
# This file is to prevent the crawling and indexing of certain parts
# of your site by web crawlers and spiders run by sites like Yahoo!
# and Google. By telling these "robots" where not to go on your site,
# you save bandwidth and server resources.
#
# This file will be ignored unless it is at the root of your host:
# Used:    http://example.com/robots.txt
# Ignored: http://example.com/site/robots.txt
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/robots.html
#
# For syntax checking, see:
# http://www.sxw.org.uk/computing/robots/check.html

# Website Sitemap
Sitemap: http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml

# Crawlers Setup
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 10

# Allowable Index
Allow: /*?p=
Allow: /index.php/blog/
Allow: /catalog/seo_sitemap/category/
Allow: /catalogsearch/result/

# Directories
Disallow: /404/
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /magento/
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /report/
Disallow: /skin/
Disallow: /stats/
Disallow: /var/

# Paths (clean URLs)
Disallow: /index.php/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /control/
Disallow: /contacts/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customize/
Disallow: /newsletter/
Disallow: /poll/
Disallow: /review/
Disallow: /sendfriend/
Disallow: /tag/
Disallow: /wishlist/

# Files
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /STATUS.txt

# Paths (no clean URLs)
Disallow: /*.js$
Disallow: /*.css$
Disallow: /*.php$
Disallow: /*?p=*&
Disallow: /*?SID=
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use mod_rewrite for this, as that is overkill in this situation.  Sometimes the SID is needed, and should not be stripped out of the URL.

You could do what B00MER recommended AND follow the best practices laid out by Google:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

For example you would add the following to that pages header:

Both the robots.txt and the canonical URL combined should really fix any SEO worries you might have.

Good luck!

Comment: ok, i see your point (and thanks for the explanations) - but right now there are URLs with SIDs in googls index which lead to 404s -and i would like to redirect them to the correct page (the one without the SIDs) as long as they come up in searches.